# Updating Solr Field Value

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

is there any possibility to update a value of a Solr-Field without reindexing the whole document?

Comment: delete the post and then insert a new one

Answer (score 1):

Nope.
You need to index the document again with all the fields.
Solr will delete and insert the document again.

There is [nice talk](http://www.searchworkings.org/movies/-/content/training/382052) about it you may want to hear.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available in the Solr version 4.0. That version is still in Beta, but will most likely be released before the end of the year. Please see the post - [Solr 4.0: Partial documents update](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/) for more details on how this works.

Comment: Good to know that anyway all fields must be stored and underneath Solr does delete the document and then reindexes it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change a single field of a document you will have to reindex the whole document, as solr does not support updating of a field only.